# Does IBM WebSphere MQ support a 64 bit client on windows?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, ibm-mq

I'm porting a C++ 32 bit application to 64 bit on windows. The application is a client of IBM WebSphere MQ. It uses the MQ client API.

Now, as the port progresses, I'm trying to find a 64 bit client. So far, no luck.

Does anyone here happen to know if where I can find one or confirm that there isn't one?

Answer (score 3):

Websphere MQ 7 for Windows supports x86 and x64, but not Itanium 64-bit.  It only **officially** supports Visual C++ 2005 for development at the moment but IBM usually issues PTFs for toleration on a regular basis so it shouldn't be too long before C++ 2008 support is there.

The statements of support and requirements are hosted on IBM web pages at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg27011920 if you're interested in further details.

Comment: Isn't MQ 7 only in Beta as of now?

Comment: ESD (electronic delivery) and media packs were both available in June 2008.

Comment: Can I download *just* the Windows client part of MQ7 somewhere?? I am using Vista 64-bit and can't seem to install my Websphere MQ Client v6.0 anymore :-(

Comment: @marc_s: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24019253&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en

Answer (score 1):

Since this is getting lots of views, let's provide the direct link to [the WMQ V7 client download](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24019253&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en). Note that it DOES support 64-bit Windows clients in some versions of Windows.

[The System Requirements page for WMQ v7.0.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg27011920) now lists Visual Studio 2008 as supported.

Note that some of the supporting code is 32 bit so the client installs to the *Program Files (x86)* directory.

The IA94 SupportPac referenced by another poster implements the JMS API over C++ and the supported environments for that SupportPac are a subset of those for the WMQ client.  If you are not using the SupportPac, refer to the link above for System Requirements instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found this page on IBM's site: [IA94: IBM Message Service Client for C/C++](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24007092). On it there is a link to a [readme.txt file](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/integration/support/supportpacs/individual/ia94.readme.txt) which, under "Supported environments" lists "Windows 2003 Server x64 edition - Microsoft Visual C++ .NET 2005 Service Pack1".

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is a different package than the WMQ Client which is what the original post asked about.  I've posted a link to the Supported Environments page in my response.